# Redirect if a logged in user accesses /login: access_control roles

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I set up the basic system to redirect non-login users to the login page

```
// security.yaml
main:
  lazy: true
  provider: app_user_provider

  form_login:
    # "login" is the name of the route created previously
    login_path: login
    check_path: login

[...]

  access_control:
  - { path: ^/home, roles: ROLE_USER }
  - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Everything works perfectly! When I'm not logged in, it redirects me properly to my login page.
On the other hand, when I am connected, I want the user to be redirected to home instead of having an error (which I currently have).

[image: WHEN A LOGIN USER GOES TO LOGIN]

I know that the error is normal but I would like a redirection I find it cleaner, a redirection with an error message would be even better.

Here is my controller :

```
class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
  #[Route('/login', name: 'login')]
public function index(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', [
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ]);
}
}
```

My controller is similar to the symfony documentation at :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#form-login

Comment: can you show us your authenticator ?

Comment: what are you talking about ? From my login controller?

Comment: Is everything login related happening in your login controller ? Then show us your login controller as well.

Hard to really answer without knowing how you implemented your authentication.

Comment: Do you more code in `src/Security` such as a `LoginFormAuthenticator` ?

Comment: No I don't have more

Comment: I posted another answer about your issue, do not hesitate to accept the answer if it satisfies you so that the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a redirect in your login method so that if the user is logged in, he will be redirected to any page you want.

You can autowire `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;` in your method to retrieve the logged in user (if its the case) without having to use `TokenStorage`.

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, UserInterface $user = null): Response
{
    if($user !== null){
        $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had thought of this solution here but according to several articles and opinions that I put below, I am looking for a more orthodox solution and in the standards:

"First idea that comes to mind. Well, it's kinda naive approach, but it works. Copy-paste three controllers and voilá tests just passed. It's just three pages, so it's ok, isn't it?

```
class SomeController extends BaseController
{
  public function someAction()
  {
    if ($this->isUserLogged()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('somewhere');
    }
    // do default action
  }
}
```

Duplication in multiple controllers can become massive problem. Just imagine the code if every action needs to do such check. For example if you want to force users to change password every month? On top of that if you are using FOSUserBundle (or any other external user bundle) you have to override 3rd bundle's controllers. That's a lot of boilerplate code, so I'd rather avoid this solution. Don't repeat my mistakes and read StackOverflow more carefully :) "

So here is the article, and indeed if I want to restrict for example the administration page to my role:

```
# - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

"
I will not test if the user is admin on all pages manually? I'm looking for a standard solution... but thanks for suggesting

Comment: You did not link any article. I do not understand your point. If you do not want user logged in to access your login page, then why would you duplicate this code elsewhere ?  There are a lot of solutions on how to handle redirect, event listeners, access controls and so on. If your issue is not just about redirecting to a specific page to another you may want to reformulate your question. For example, what do you mean with "For example if you want to force users to change password every month", how is it related with redirecting a logged in user ?

Comment: This is the article between the quotation marks

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/w0yyag/redirect-authenticated-user-on-anonymous-pages-in-symfony

Comment: You never said about having multiple anonymous route to redirect to the homepage. Using an event listener like the article would be pointless in the case where you only want to redirect when accessing your login page. Next time you post a question on SO, try to be more specific or the answer won't be.

Comment: Still not clear what you are asking but if you want to run some generic code before the controller's action is executed then make yourself a kernel controller event subscriber.